# disabling a row based on dataSource property - antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd

In antd table, while rendering the data can i make a row as disabled.

so i have a dataSource so while rendering the table i need to make a table row as disabled based on the dataSource property.

In the dataSource there is a property of enabled, if its false i need to make the row as disabled kind of css.

first i thought of having a className but is there any inbuilt way, i dont want to have the selected kind of checkbox just plane a row to be disabled.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const dataSource = [
    {
      key: "1",
      name: "Mike",
      age: 32,
      address: "10 Downing Street",
      enabled: true
    },
    {
      key: "2",
      name: "John",
      age: 42,
      address: "10 Downing Street",
      enabled: false
    }
  ];

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      key: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      dataIndex: "age",
      key: "age"
    },
    {
      title: "Address",
      dataIndex: "address",
      key: "address"
    }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-sun-n8o6v)

is there any way for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to find the solution

in App.js

```
     <Table dataSource={dataSource} rowClassName={record => !record.enabled && "disabled-row"}
 columns={columns} />;
```

and in css file

```
.disabled-row {
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
    }
```